# When upgrading EF6, I get the default XML namespace of the project must be the MSBuild XML namespace

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am upgrading my EntityFramework from version 6.2.0 to 6.3.0 but during the upgrade I get the error:

> The default XML namespace of the project must be the MSBuild XML namespace. If the project is authored in the MSBuild 2003 format, please add xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" to the  element. If the project has been authored in the old 1.0 or 1.2 format, please convert it to MSBuild 2003 format.

My .Net Framework is 4.5.2. Can someone help please? Thanks.

Please note I have seen all equivalent questions on Stackoverflow but they don't seem to help.

Comment: Facing the same issue with 6.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, EF 6.3 uses the new csproj format and requires VS 2017 and above.
I degraded to EF 6.2 and it built fine.
So for your case, please try with VS2017 or above to build the project.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, it looks like it. I guess I leave it as it is then.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio Community 2019 locally, but I'm getting this error when deploying to Azure, for the same reason. Downgrading to EF 6.2 makes it work. Could you please have a look at my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58617182/azure-deployment-error-msb4041-the-default-xml-namespace-of-the-project-must-b

Answer (score 1):

Entity Framework 6.3.0 still doesn't work, but 6.4.0 does.