# MSBuild MSB4041 Error on Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: .net, jenkins, msbuild

I have a .NET Framework 4.7.2 application and I am trying to build this on Jenkins with MSBuild plugin. I have installed Microsoft.Net.Compilers.Toolset Nuget package.
I am getting this error :

> Microsoft.Net.Compilers.Toolset.props(2,1): error MSB4041: The default
> XML namespace of the project must be the MSBuild XML namespace. If the
> project is authored in the MSBuild 2003 format, please add
> xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" to the
>  element. If the project has been authored in the old 1.0 or
> 1.2 format, please convert it to MSBuild 2003 format.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure deployment: error MSB4041: The default XML namespace of the project must be the MSBuild XML namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58617182/azure-deployment-error-msb4041-the-default-xml-namespace-of-the-project-must-b)